# RxAndroid blocks my UI

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, android-room, android-jetpack

I am new to RxAndroid and tried the same with Room database. But the problem is that when inserting data into a database, then the progress bar that I am showing getting blocked and being sluggish. I referred [this blog](https://medium.com/@alahammad/database-with-room-using-rxjava-764ee6124974) for the project

```
public void insertBillPayments(final CallBackParams params,
                               BillPaymentsOffline... payments) {
    Completable.fromAction(() -> db.daoAccess().insertBillPayments(payments))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    params.getCallback().onOrderAdded(params);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    params.getCallback().onDataNotAvailable(params);
                }
            });
}
```

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: The rx code seems correct and the Action provided (insert record into the db) is not executed in the UI thread. Could you please post the code related to the progress bar?

Comment: U were right @Lino, the problem was not with rx code. I was doing another long running process before calling above method. Thanks for divert me into the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems fine, but I would recommend that you switch your `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` calls for clarity as `subscribeOn` applies to the stream and `observeOn` applies to the emitted values and functions applied after it.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html